# Extracting Textures from model

Tags: texturing

So I am trying to figure out how to export the model textures keeping the gold, carbon, and white shaders I put on it, to a tga file. But for some reason it isn't coloring over the Image Texture I originally put onto the weapon. Could someone tell me how to extract the textures without me having to restart this whole project.

Thanks, James.[image: Below is the weapon I wish to extract the textures from]

[link to download the Blender Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wyAuE8mDCdM4BCZfce61efc5g7oMeH9K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In the image editor (the left window on your screenshot), click on `Image` then `Save as` or hover your mouse on the image and press `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `S` it will allow you to save the image texture.

Comment: Yes but, I am trying to make the weapon to the left look like the weapon to the right. So I am able to extract it into a tga file for a mod pak

Comment: Which weapon on the left, I see only one weapon?

Comment: The texture for the weapon I mean, the image texture.

Comment: So the texture on the left is not the one used for the weapon on the right? If so, you can bake the textures from the object to a new image file and save it as an external image.